# Performance disparity between interactive iSeries/DB2 SQL, and the same query called from C#

Tags: c#, sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a query to a DB2 database on an iSeries that I wish to run from a C# program. The query is:

```
SELECT C.CLINO, SUM(T.VALUE) AS VALUE 
FROM GTDATA.CLIENT AS C 
INNER JOIN TABLE(GETHOLDDTL(C.CLINO,20150630,'','Y','Y','','','','','','','','','','M')) AS T ON T.CLIENT = C.CLINO 
GROUP BY C.CLINO
```

GETHOLDDTL is an SQL function supplied to us by a third party to allow us to retrieve data from their system in our own programs.

When I run the query in the iSeries interactive SQL environment, saving the output to a file to ensure that I'm getting a time for the execution over the whole dataset, it takes approximately 1.5 hours to run. This is fine, as there's a lot of data which is being calculated on the fly. The problem is that when I run my C# program, the process takes in excess of 24 hours (ie that's the point at which I gave up, when it hadn't got past this point the morning after I started execution).

The C# code I'm using to execute the query is:

```
var conn = new OdbcConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = @"FILEDSN=S:\qsys2.dsn;UID=XXXXXXX;PWD=XXXXXXXX";

conn.ConnectionTimeout = 0;
conn.Open();
var com = new OdbcCommand(selectCommand, conn);
var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

conn.Close();
```

The delay is happening on the dt.Load() line - this is presumably where the query is actually executed?

What might account for the difference? Is there a better way to implement this? If necessary, I can produce the data using the interactive SQl environment, and change my C# code to use the file that produces, but I'm trying to get this to run without any user interaction so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This creates C# objects for every row loaded into the table, which is why it  takes so long.  You'd have the same issue consuming the file. Do you need to load the table into the application memory?

Comment: I agree with dbugger.  If you want a fair comparison you should be using a `OdbcReader` to read the results and write them to a file instead.  Also I strongly recommend putting your connection and command objects into `using` statements.

Comment: dbugger - I don't necessarily need to have everything in memory - I inherited this application, with the requirement to speed it up (while being new to C#). I know the approach saving the query output to a file is faster, as I did this as a workaround when I was first assigned the task, I'm now trying to find a proper solution. A rewrite is looking more appealing by the minute.

juharr - I can't find a class called OdbcReader, did you mean OdbcDataReader? I'm not familiar with "using" beyond it being the C# equivalent of #include - I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: I'd write the function getholddtl in-line on any db (if possible).  The database can't optimize a function.

Comment: Hmm, I'd probably actually dump it to a temp table, or whatever db table the final location is directly (ie, via `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`), then read from _that_ in C#.  What's the ultimate destination/use of the data?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - the data is joined with some other data, and put into a big `List<>` using some almost unreadable LINQ. The whole thing is a mess.

The code sample is from a method that has `selectCommand` passed into it. I've ended up creating a copy of this method for this case, but instead of returning a `DataTable` I'm using the `OdbcDataReader` to fill and return a `List` of a class that contains just the returned data and allows me to rationalise the calling method a bit. It's not ideal but it's better than it was, including vastly improved performance.